# How to generate heatmap in ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new application and added the gem 'heatmap' in gemfile of map. I then did a `bundle install`, but I do not know on how to write the heatmap code on which file.

This is what I tried:

```
map = Heatmap.new
map << Heatmap::Area.new(1, 10)
map << Heatmap::Area.new(5, 20)
map << Heatmap::Area.new(17, 10)
map << Heatmap::Area.new(25, 38)
map << Heatmap::Area.new(35, 70)
map << Heatmap::Area.new(15, 90)
map << Heatmap::Area.new(27, 60)
map.output('simple.png')
```

Comment: Please explain step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you're trying to use the Heatmap gem (https://github.com/hyfen/heatmap, last commit on Nov 9, 2013)

Try initializing the Heatmap object this way `Heatmap::Map.new` as the README says, and then add the points `heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(0, 0, 0.1)`

Usage would be this way:

```
require 'heatmap'

heatmap = Heatmap::Map.new

heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(0, 0, 0.1)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(80, 5, 0.3)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(10, 5, 0.2)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(23, 5, 0.8)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(50, 50, 0.9)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(20, 10, 0.9)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(100, 85, 1.0)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(100, 60, 1.0)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(90, 90, 1.0)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(90, 30, 0.8)
heatmap.points << Heatmap::Point.new(90, 45, 0.9)

heatmap.output("Russia terrorist state.png")
```

Comment: I am created new application in ruby on rails. Added gem heatmap but does not found next step of create heatmap using this code.

Comment: Do it in a view to see if it's really working, then and if the data is dynamic you can send it by the controller as an instance variable.

Comment: Is it possible if user click on page then create heatmap.

Comment: Of course it's possible, just capture the click on a button or a "a" tag and send the info. through AJAX. Cheers.

Comment: Then send the data through the controller to the view and this will be shown directly to the user when the view is loaded. If you wanna do it this way and have more doubts, it'd be better to make a new question.

Comment: If user click on the page then generate  heatmap on the page. Not directory. How it possible.

Comment: The heatmap will be generated when the user makes the request to the route, which responds with the view and the controller sends the corresponding data. Show me what you've done and I'll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

We made a gem to generate, save and display heatmap data. The gem uses famous js [library](https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/) to show the generated data.

https://github.com/Qbatch/heatmap-rails